# How to create two different register forms for two different type of users with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project which allows business to add their local store based on their location. There is a register form for businesses which has been created extending the user model and uses email for account verification. So far, this functionality works really well.

Here is my **models.py**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
activated_key = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def send_activation_email(self):
    if not self.activated:
        self.activated_key = code_generator()
        self.save()
        path_ = reverse('activate', kwargs={'code': self.activated_key})
        subject = 'Activa tu cuenta :)'
        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
        message = 'Activa tu cuenta haciendo click aquí' + path_
        recipient_list = [self.user.email]
        html_message = '<h1>Activa tu cuenta haciendo click <a href="{path_}"aquí</a>.</h1>'.format(path_=path_)
        print(html_message)

        sent_mail = False
        return sent_mail

def post_save_user_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
if created:
    profile, is_created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(post_save_user_receiver, sender=User)
```

And here my model for businesses:

```
class Business(models.Model):
owner = models.OneToOneField(User, null=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
logo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=False, upload_to=upload_location)
```

Here is my RegistrationForm on **form.py**:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
fields, plus a repeated password."""
password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email',)

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    qs = User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email)
    if qs.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Este email ya se está usando por otro usuario. Prueba con otro.')
    return email

def clean_password2(self):
    # Check that the two password entries match
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
    return password2

def save(self, commit=True):
    # Save the provided password in hashed format
    user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    user.is_active = False
    # create a new user hash for activating email.

    if commit:
        user.save()
        print(user.profile)
        user.profile.send_activation_email()

    return user
```

What I'd like to accomplish next is to create another registration form for users (not businesses) which are only allowed to comment on the business DetailView. Ideally, those users could register with social accounts and email but those users should be in another SQL table and have no relationship with businesses.

I've read a lot about having multiple users in django and it seems a difficult task. There are different methods which I could apply:

- Having another model inside my models.py but I think that could create problems with my Business Model
- Create another app for users and other for businesses, but I've never done that before
- Using the AbstractUser but that'd involve sharing the main register form and I want thwo different forms for each type of user.

How could I do it?

Thank you in advance!